# why could not get results of mysql query in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, null

I'm making a test login page using php, javascript. but, I can not get a result of select query in php. What was the wrong in my code?

Thank you for your help.

This is my local table 
[image]

And This is what I entered email(id), password in a login page. 
[image]

(apache2 - error.log)

> [Mon Jan 15 17:22:55.208889 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 12752:tid 1396]
>   [client ::1:54512] mysqli_result::__set_state(array(\n 'current_field'
>   => NULL,\n 'field_count' => NULL,\n 'lengths' => NULL,\n 'num_rows' => NULL,\n 'type' => NULL,\n)),
>   referer: http://localhost/sharepractice/index.php?id=signin

**(signin.js)**

```
var save = document.getElementById('btnSignIn');
btnSignIn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if ($('#inputEmail').val() == '' ||
      $('#inputPassword').val() == '' ) {
    alert("check input.");
    window.location.search = "?id=signin";
  }
  else {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    url: './signin.php',
    data: {
      email: $('#inputEmail').val(),
      password: $('#inputPassword').val()
      },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        window.location.href = "index.php"
      },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
        window.location.search = "?id=signin";
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**(signin.php)**

```
<?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "spman";
    $mysql_password = "spman";
    $mysql_database = "sharepractice";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $mysql_database);

    $query = "select email, nickname from userinfo where vald = 'Y' and email = '".$_POST['email']."' and password = '".$_POST['password']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    error_log(var_export($result, 1));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    error_log(var_export($count, 1));
    if ($count == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($return);
        error_log(var_export($row, 1));
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row[0];
        $_SESSION['nickname'] = $row[1];
        $return = array ('result'=&gt;true, 'message'=&gt;"success");
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
    else {
        $return = array ('result'=&gt;false, 'message'=&gt;"fail");
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ Fix your input validation!

Comment: I'm going to guess that it is the misspelling of valid/vald, but that's a guess based on the limited information provided. Please provide a clear question. More importantly, ensure that your code is secure.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added more information. Please help me.